# Invert MinMaxScaler from scikit_learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

To feed my generative neural net, I need to normalize some data between -1 and 1.

I do it with `MinMaxScaler` from Sklearn and it works great.
Now, my generator is going to output data between -1 and 1.

How to revert `MinMaxScaler` to get real data ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do that with [inverse transform](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform).

Answer (score 34):

Let us start by defining a pandas dataframe:

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,3],[1.02,1.2],[0.5,0.3]]),columns=cols)
```

[image]

The we scale the data using the MinMaxScaler

```
scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data[cols])
```

[image]

Now, to invert the transformation you should call the inverse transform:

```
scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_data)
```

[image]

Comment: But with this approach you lose your column names.

Comment: How can I transform back for example only column B?

Comment: @NikolayFrick To retain column names: `df[list(df.columns)] = scaler.transform(df)` works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rev_min_max_func(scaled_val):
    max_val = max(df['target'])
    min_val = min(df['target'])
    og_val = (scaled_val*(max_val - min_val)) + min_val
    return og_val
df['pred_target'] = scaled_labeled_df['pred_scaled_target'].apply(lambda x: rev_min_max_func(x))
```

Even this works for me!

Comment: you have three different column names here. `target`, `pred_scaled_target` and `target`. .. what does `target` refer to? I am 82% sure I know what the first two are.