# Using inverse_transform MinMaxScaler from scikit_learn to force a dataframe be in a range of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054147/5081366) to apply an inverse transformation over a scaled dataframe. My question is how can I do to transform a new one dataframe to a range of values of the original dataframe?. 
So far, I did this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
cols = ['A', 'B']
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,3],[1.02,1.2],[0.5,0.3]]),columns=cols)
scaler = MinMaxScaler() # default min and max values are 0 and 1, respectively
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data)
orig_data = scaler.inverse_transform(scaled_data) # obtain same as `data`
new_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[8,20],[11,2],[5,3]]),columns=cols)
inver_new_data = scaler.inverse_transform(new_data)
```

I want `inver_new_data` will be a dataframe with its columns in the same range of values of `data` columns, for instance, column A between 0.5 and 2, and so on. However I get for column A values between 8 and 17. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MinMaxScaler` applies to each column the following transformation:

1. Subtract column minimum;
2. Divide by column range (i.e. `column max - column min`).

The inverse transform applies the "inverse" operation in "inverse" order:

1. Multiply by column range before the transformation;
2. Add the column min.

Therefore for column `A` is doing

```
(df['A'] - df['A'].min())/(df['A'].max() - df['A'].min())
```

in particular the scaler stores the min `0.5` and the range `1.5`

When you apply the `inverse_transform` to `[8, 11, 5]` this becomes:

```
[8*1.5 + 0.5, 11*1.5 + 0.5, 5*1.5 + 0.5]=[12.5, 18, 8]
```

Now, this is **not** suggested in general to do any machine learning, however to transform the ranges of the new column to the previous one, you can do something like the following:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,3],[1.02,1.2],[0.5,0.3]]),columns=cols)

# Create a Scaler for the initial data
scaler_data = MinMaxScaler() 

# Fit the scaler with these data, but there is no need to transform them.
scaler_data.fit(data)

#Create new data
new_data = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[8,20],[11,2],[5,3]]),columns=cols)

# Create a Scaler for the new data
scaler_new_data = MinMaxScaler() 

# Trasform new data in the [0-1] range
scaled_new_data = scaler_new_data.fit_transform(new_data)

# Inverse transform new data from [0-1] to [min, max] of data
inver_new_data = scaler_data.inverse_transform(scaled_new_data)
```

For example this will always map the min and max of new dataframe columns to the min and max of initial dataframe columns respectively.

Comment: The problem is I want to have each column of `new_data`  in the range of each column of `data`

Comment: That's what I wanted! In `inver_new_data = scaler_data.inverse_transform(new_data)` should be `inver_new_data = scaler_data.inverse_transform(scaled_new_data)`. Thanks! I have a doubt about your comment `this is not suggested in general to do any machine learning`, why is this?

Comment: @mjbsgll Yes you are correct, it is `scaled_new_data` to pass there. Ok unless you have a reason to do that from some other information, you should avoid doing that. As I mention, you are mapping different values to the same one, and this is not ok. What you should do is scale your training data with a fitted Scaler, and use the same to scale new/test/validation data. In any other way you either have a leak, a bias or just an illogical pipeline

Comment: My reason to do this is, in order to train a decision tree, I have to do it using a combination of two sources of data, one of them isn't scaled and the other it is. So, as also I have to compare with other predictions results make from models trained without scaled data (because decision tree don't need scaled data due it works with entropy, not distances), my workaround was to create an "unscaled" data from the scaled one with the aim to have all in the same scale.

Comment: Then it looks like you have information about the data to take that decision :)

Answer (score 2):

To explain you what is `MinMaxScaler` [doing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html):

```
X_std = (X - X.min(axis=0)) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))
X_scaled = X_std * (max - min) + min
```

So basically every feature of your `data`will be between 0 and 1.
The moment you run: `fit_transform(data)`, is trained.

For transformation you have:

```
X_scaled = scale * X + min - X.min(axis=0) * scale
```

where `scale = (max - min) / (X.max(axis=0) - X.min(axis=0))`
the scale was trained from the fitting method.

So if you run  `inverse_transofmr(new_data)` this does not help you at all.

Also `inver_new_data= scaler.transform(new_data)` will not help you.

You need to precise what the same range means for you? The approach with `MinMaxScaler`will not help you right now. You could only limit the columns to the min and max of the original dataframe. So for example:

```
dataA = new_data[['A']]
scalerA = MinMaxScaler(data['A'].min(), data['A'].max()) 
inver_new_data_A = scaler.fit_transform(dataA)
```

but this is also not th exact range, `minmax`also respects the distances between the points.

Comment: The same range means if column A of `data` has values between [0.5, 2], I would like to scale the column A of `new_data` from the range [5, 11] to  [0.5, 2], and so on with each column.

Comment: I supposed you mean `scalerA` in this line `inver_new_data_A = scaler.fit_transform(new_data[['A']]) `, so I've tried it and I got and error:  `IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.`   I'm going to research that error

Comment: Thanks, but I think the other answer fits better to my problem because in yours I have to do column by column, and the other workaround does it all at the same time